# Resizing height in Shape Drawable

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-shape

I have a shape drawable resource file. 
it's the drawable.xml code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="-2dp"
          android:bottom="-2dp"
          android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/px02"
                    android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and this is layout xml code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray333"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!!!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_category_border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the result is this.

[image]

you can see the white bar on the left side. 
and i want to make the bar size shorter top and bottom as high as the TextView's text.(the red line) 
i tried to give a padding and size in the drawable.xml. 
and i set android:includeFontPadding on the TextView.
but it didn't work. 
how can i make it??

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do it like this

[image]

It was little bit tricky to remove padding from bottom and top, but you can try the following xml and do some adjustments as u like.

**bg_category_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**layout xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3C3C3C"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_category_border"
        >

        <TextView
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!!!"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Margin attribute dosen't have -dp.